# All variables in new object are set to zero, despite default arguments in constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, clion, default-constructor, default-arguments

I am writing a student project. For some reason all variables of this object are set to 0 or false, despite the fact that the constructor have default arguments set. The class of this object inherit after another class. So, it looks like this:

```
class Weapon
public:
constructor()
[some functions]
private:
[some variables]
class WeaponShortBow : inherit publicly after Weapon
public:
constructor (default arguments)
[one other function]
private:
[nothing]
```

The constructor is being called inside the constructor of object of other class.

here is code:

Weapon.h

```
#ifndef DNDTESTY_WEAPON_H
#define DNDTESTY_WEAPON_H
#include "Effects/Effect.h"

class Weapon {
public:
    Weapon();

    void removeAmmo();

    int getRange() const;

    int and_so_on() const;

private:
    int Amunition;
    int Range;
    int TypeOfDice;
    int NumberOfDice;
    int HitModiff;
    bool IsFniesse;
    bool IsTwoHanded;
    bool IsMagical;
    bool IsLight;
    char Category;
    Effect *effect;
};
```

Weapon.cpp

```
#include "Weapon.h"

Weapon::Weapon(){
}

void Weapon::removeAmmo() {
    this->Amunition += -1;
}

int Weapon::getRange() const {
    return Range;
}

int Weapon::and_so_on() const {
    return and_so_on;
}
```

WeaponShortBow.h

```
#include "Effects/Effect.h"
#include "Effects/NoEffect.h"
#include "Weapon.h"

class WeaponShortBow : public Weapon{
public:
    WeaponShortBow(int Amunition = 12,
                   int Range = 24,
                   int TypeOfDice = 6,
                   int NumberOfDice = 1,
                   int HitModiff = 0,
                   bool IsFniesse = false,
                   bool IsTwoHanded = true,
                   bool IsMagical = false,
                   bool IsLight = false,
                   char Category = 'R');

    ~WeaponShortBow();

    Effect* ApplyShortBowEffect();
private:

};
```

WeaponShortBow.cpp

```
#include "WeaponShortBow.h"
#include "Effects/NoEffect.h"

WeaponShortBow::WeaponShortBow(
        int Amunition,
        int Range,
        int TypeOfDice,
        int NumberOfDice,
        int HitModiff,
        bool IsFniesse,
        bool IsTwoHanded,
        bool IsMagical,
        bool IsLight,
        char Category){
}

Effect* WeaponShortBow::ApplyShortBowEffect(){
    Effect* tmp = new NoEffect;
    return tmp;
}
```

the pointer to this object is stored here
Actor.h

```
#include <string>
#include "DiceRoller.h"
#include "Weapons/Weapon.h"
#include "Weapons/WeaponShortBow.h"
#include "Weapons/Effects/Effect.h"

using namespace std;

class Actor {
public:

    Actor(string name, char token);
    virtual ~Actor();

    string name;
    char token;

    int some_functions();


private:

    int totalHP = 12;
    int lostHP = 0;

    int totalAC = 12;
    int lostAc = 0;

    int initiativeBonus = 0;
    int proficiency = 0;
    int speed = 6;

    int AbStr=14;
    int ModStr=(AbStr-10)/2;
    int AbDex=12;
    int ModDex=(AbDex-10)/2;
    int AbCon=12;
    int ModCon=(AbCon-10)/2;
    int AbInt=12;
    int ModInt=(AbInt-10)/2;
    int AbWis=12;
    int ModWis=(AbWis-10)/2;
    int AbCha=12;
    int ModCha=(AbCha-10)/2;

    Weapon* weapon;
    Effect* effect;

};
```

and here is Actor.cpp

```
#include "Actor.h"

using namespace std;

Actor::Actor(string name, char token) {
    this->name=name;
    this->token=token;
    this->weapon= new WeaponShortBow;
}
Actor::~Actor(){}


void Actor::reciveDmg(int dmg){
    this->lostHP=(this->lostHP)+dmg;
}

void Actor::some other functions(){}
```

I tried giving the values to the constructor in braces, but it does not seem to solve the problem. I also changed the type of pointer in actor.h from Weapon* to WeaponShortBow*, and instead of giving the default arguments in constructor, give them value in WeaponShortBow.h in private: like this
private:
int whatever = 2;

Comment: You pass a bunch of arguments to your `WeaponShortBow` constructor and then proceed to do nothing with them. You need to actually save them in class member variables.

Comment: Example, `struct Xyz { int data; Xyz(int value = 77); };` and then `Xyz::Xyz(int value) : data{value} {}`.  *Voila!*

Comment: `Weapon::Weapon() {}` -- This leaves all of those member variables uninitialized.  You should initialize all of your member variables to something coherent.

Comment: IMHO, your `WeaponShortBow` should call one of the parent constructors.  Being explicit doesn't hurt when coding.

Comment: One other thing to note is that naming a variable the same in some different scope does not make it the same variable. In `WeaponShortBow::WeaponShortBow(   int Amunition,  int Range, int TypeOfDice, ...)` the variables `Amunition`, `Range` ... are all local variables in the constructor. They have no connection to variables of the same name in the base class. They are totally separate.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie   Actually, `Weapon::Weapon() {}` leaves the members default-initialised.      That can work out to leaving members uninitialised, but not always - it depends on both the type of the members and how the instance of `Weapon` is defined.

Answer (score 3):

- `WeaponShortBow` takes a bunch of arguments, but does nothing with them. They are not automatically stored in the base class, `Weapon`.
- Currently, there is no way for `WeaponShortBow` to actually store the arguments in the base class. The member variables are `private` and the base class, `Weapon`, has no constructor for accepting the arguments.

Consider this simplified version with only one of the arguments. `Weapon` here has a constructor taking the argument `Ammunition`. I've made it `protected` so that only derived classes can use it, but that's optional:

```cpp
class Weapon {
public:
    Weapon() = default; // no need to provide an empty implementation this way

    int getAmmo() const;

protected: // if only derived classes should be able to use the constructor
    Weapon(int Ammunition);

private:
    int m_ammunition = 0; // used when default initialized
};

class WeaponShortBow : public Weapon{
public:
    WeaponShortBow(int Ammunition = 12);
};
```

The `Weapon` constructor taking the `Ammunition` parameter uses the [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) to initialize the member variable with the value given to the constructor:

```cpp
Weapon::Weapon(int Ammunition) : m_ammunition(Ammunition) {}
int Weapon::getAmmo() const { return m_ammunition; }
```

Similarly, the `WeaponShortBow` constructor taking the `Ammunition` parameter uses that to initialize the base class:

```cpp
WeaponShortBow::WeaponShortBow(int Ammunition) : Weapon(Ammunition) {}
```

So, the initialization goes:
`WeaponShortBow` constructor -> `Weapon` constructor -> `Weapon` member variable.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8cdE7h7vM)